# Как изменить размер вызываемого окна с графиком matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Как я могу регулировать ширину/высоту/название окна, которое открывается при создании графика с помощью matplotlib?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы получилось например такое окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте, наконец, документацию и туториалы, чтоли...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(w,h)
```

где w и h ширина и высота, где значения надо указывать в дюймах (10х10) у меня уже половина всего экрана. А что касается названия окна, то его изменить можно следующим образом:

```
fig = pylab.gcf()
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Graph')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]